# ndb to_dict method does not include object's key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am leveraging ndb's to_dict method to convert an object's properties into a python dict. From everything I can tell, this method does not include the object's key or parent within the dict as per the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model_to_dict

However for my situation I need the key to be in the dict. My preference would be to leverage the builtin method and subclass it or something similar rather than create my own to_dict method.

What is the best way to accomplish this or am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

FYI: I am not leveraging django for this project but instead straight python deployed up to gae.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You're not missing anything ;-)

Just add the key to the dictionary after you call to_dict, and yes override the method.

If you have multiple models that don't share the same base class with your custom to_dict, I would implement it as a mixin.

to define to_dict as a method of a Mixin class.  you would

```
class ModelUtils(object):
    def to_dict(self):
        result = super(ModelUtils,self).to_dict()
        result['key'] = self.key.id() #get the key as a string
        return result
```

Then to use it.

```
class MyModel(ModelUtils,ndb.Model):
    # some properties etc...
```

Comment: Thanks Tim! Worked perfectly. I am new to python and don't know how to override the method as you mention. I can post that as another question unless you are willing to edit your answer and provide some guidance. I appreciate the quick response and have enjoyed learning from you via all your other answers here on stack.

Comment: Danke sir. helped me as well

Answer (score 3):

Another easy way to achieve that (without having to override `to_dict`) is to add a `ComputedProperty` that returns the id, like so:

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):

  # this property always returns the value of self.key.id()
  uid = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.id(), indexed=False)

  # other properties ...
```

A `ComputedProperty` will be added to the result of `to_dict` just like any other property.

There are just two constraints:

1. Apparently the name of the property can not be `key` (since that would conflict with the actual key) and `id` doesn't work either.
2. This won't work if you don't specify a key or id when you create the object.

Also, the computed value will be written to the data store when you call `put()`, so it consumes some of your storage space.

An advantage is that this supports the `include` and `exclude` arguments of  `to_dict()` out of the box.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when initially creating an entity since the key hasn't yet been defined. I'm getting this error:  `uid = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.key.id())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Correct, that's what I meant by constraint #2 in my answer. You must assign a key when the object is created to make this work. At least in my uses cases that's not an issue though.

Comment: Yep, I caught it almost right after I posted my comment.  Must have missed your note the first time through. Thanks for the clarification.  I was able to get it to work by [allocating and assigning](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/creating-entity-keys#allocating_ids) a key to the entity before the initial _put_