# NDB to_dict method ignores properties defined with @property decorator

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

My NDB data model looks like this

```
class Foo(ndb.Model):
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    # some other properties

    @property
    def readable_created(self):
        return readble_time(self.created)
```

where `readable_time` returns some readable version of a DateTime (e.g. '2 days ago'). Thanks to the @property decorator, I can easily access it as `myinstance.readable_created`. I would like to use NDB's `Model.to_dict()` method to turn the data into a dictionary, say for writing it to a template. However, `readable_created` is ignored by this method and `myinstance.to_dict(include=['readable_created'])` returns `{}`.

It's the first time I use the `@property` decorator, so maybe I missed something?
Is there an easy way around this? Is this a bug?

The approach from [ndb to_dict method does not include object's key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850136/ndb-to-dict-method-does-not-include-objects-key/16850717#16850717) works, but there should be an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: Why should there be an easier way? `to_dict` is meant to serialize all the datastore properties, and `readable_created` isn't one.

Comment: I agree with @Daniel,  in addition most templating environments can access the object passed to it, you don't need to turn it into a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is by design. Some templating engines let you access attributes directly, so you won't need to use to_dict() at all (as Tim Hoffman pointed out).

Comment: Thank you, Guido. I've tried passing the entity directly and I works great.